# How to fit Frequentist meta-analysis for regression between endpoints?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, measurement-error, meta-regression

#### General Information

I have $j = 1, \dots J$ studies which report two measurements, $x_{obs, j}$ and $y_{obs, j}$, and their standard errors, $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$. Both measurements are assumed to follow normal distributions which are centered around some true value,
$$x_{obs} \sim N(x, \sigma^2_x) \text{ and } y_{obs} \sim N(y, \sigma^2_y).$$

I want to fit a regression model between the two endpoints, preferably with a random intercept for each study. I need to account for the standard errors of $x_{obs}$ and $y_{obs}$. I *think* I know how to do this with a Bayesian model (see below), but I would appreciate the feedback. For a variety of reasons, I need to fit a comparable Frequentist model. I am lost on how to fit this kind of model in a Frequentist framework

#### Bayesian Model

The observed measurements are each centered around a true value. I add a random effect, $\gamma_j$ for between-study variability.

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
y_{obs, j} \sim N(y_{j}, \sigma^2_y) \\ 
 y_{0i} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * x_j + \gamma_j \\
x_{obs, j} \sim N(x, \sigma^2_x) \\
x \sim N(0, \sigma^2) \\
\gamma_j \sim N(0, \tau) \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

$\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are given some non-informative prior.

### Frequentist Model

I have no clue how to fit this model. Maybe I can express it as a linear mixed model with certain variance components fixed?

$$y_j = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * x  + \epsilon_{y_j} + \epsilon_{x_j} + \gamma_j.$$

Comment: I would try with mvmeta package in R